# Please help strang micro warm like thing found in dogs kennel in Conyers Georgia

Tags: species-identification

I found this strange tiny warm under my five months old puppy's cage can someone please help find out what it is their was about thirty of them her cage is cleaned regularly and is dry and cozy I've checked her poop nothing in it but she is constantly scratching and losing hair rapidly no flea's on her [image]

Comment: Welcome to the site - we would need to know where in the world you are, and preferably get some better pictures and a sense of how big these "worms" are. Could the scratching be caused by shedding (spring/summer coming in the Northern hemisphere...)? Do you groom the puppy and get these off her, or were they only found on her bedding?

Comment: If you're concerned about the health of your puppy, please take them to a veterinarian.